# Iterate over $@ stored in another variable in another function

Tags: sh, argv

How can I iterate over `$@` after it has been stored in another variable in another function?

Note this is about the sh shell, not bash.

My code (super simplified):

```
#! /bin/sh

set -- a b "c d"

args=

argv() {
  shift # pretend handling options
  args="$@" # remaining arguments
}

fun() {
  for arg in "$args"; do
    echo "+$arg+"
  done
}

argv "$@"
fun
```

Output:

```
+b c d+
```

I want:

```
+b+
+c d+
```

---

The special variable `$@` stores argv preserving whitespace. The for loop can loop over `$@` also preserving whitespace.

```
set -- a b "c d"
for arg in "$@"; do
  echo "+$arg+"
done
```

Output:

```
+a+
+b+
+c d+
```

But once `$@` is assigned to another variable the whitespace preserving is gone.

```
set -- a b "c d"
args="$@"
for arg in "$args"; do
  echo "+$arg+"
done
```

Output

```
+a b c d+
```

Without quotes:

```
for arg in $args; do
  echo "+$arg+"
done
```

Output:

```
+a+
+b+
+c+
+d+
```

In bash it can be done using arrays.

```
set -- a b "c d"
args=("$@")
for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
  echo "+$arg+"
done
```

Output:

```
+a+
+b+
+c d+
```

Can that be done in the sh shell?

Comment: This is a limitation of a POSIX shell not supporting arrays or parameter expansions like `${@:2}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `shift` again inside `fun` if you know the `shift` has been performed in `argv`.

```
#! /bin/sh

set -- a b "c d"

args=

argv() {
  shifted=1 # pretend handling options
  shift $shifted
}

fun() {
  [ -n $shifted ] && shift $shifted
  for arg; do
    echo "+$arg+"
  done
}

argv "$@"
fun "$@"
```

Output:

```
+b+
+c d+
```

Comment: most excelent. the only caveat or side effect is a lingering global variable with an obscure number in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two workarounds. Both have caveats.

First workaround: put newlines between arguments then use `read`.

```
set -- a b " c d "

args=

argv() {
  shift
  for arg in "$@"; do
    args="$args$arg\n"
  done
}

fun() {
  printf "$args" | while IFS= read -r arg; do
    echo "+$arg+"
  done
}

argv "$@"
fun
```

Output:

```
+b+
+ c d +
```

Note that even the spaces before and after are preserved.

Caveat: if the arguments contain newlines you are screwed.

Second workaround: put quotes around arguments then use `eval`.

```
set -- a b " c d "

args=

argv() {
  shift
  for arg in "$@"; do
    args="$args \"$arg\""
  done
}

fun() {
  for arg in "$@"; do
    echo "+$arg+"
  done
}

argv "$@"
eval fun "$args"
```

Caveat: if the arguments contain quotes you are screwed.